# Python print format of integers and string mix

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format

```
line = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,300]


GroupCount = 0
FormatDesignators =line[0]

for i in range(1 ,len(line)):
    if line[i] != line[i - 1] + 1:
        if GroupCount >= 1:
            FormatDesignators = FormatDesignators,'-', line[i - 1]
            FormatDesignators = FormatDesignators,',',line[i]
            GroupCount = 0
    else:
        GroupCount = GroupCount + 1
print(FormatDesignators)


if GroupCount >= 1:
    FormatDesignators = FormatDesignators,"-",line[i]
    print (FormatDesignators)
```

Right now it is outputting:

> ((((((1, '-', 7), ',', 9), '-', 12), ',', 14), '-', 19), ',', 300)
> and I want it to be 1-7,9-12,14-19,300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
line = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,300]


GroupCount = 0
FormatDesignators =line[0]

for i in range(1 ,len(line)):
    if line[i] != line[i - 1] + 1:
        if GroupCount >= 1:
            FormatDesignators = f'{FormatDesignators} - {line[i - 1]},'
            FormatDesignators = f'{FormatDesignators} {line[i]}'
            GroupCount = 0
    else:
        GroupCount = GroupCount + 1
print(FormatDesignators)


if GroupCount >= 1:
    FormatDesignators = f'{FormatDesignators} - {line[i]},'
    print (FormatDesignators)
```

Comment: This code works - for original "assignment" (question). However, it's not very Pythonic and not using the best feature of Python.  I feel it's prob. not a good way to learn the language.  (Just my $.02!)

Comment: I dint bother changing the code just wanted to get the proper output syntax, so just edited the original code to make sure its working

Comment: no offense. Just speak from the "learning perspective."  That's for the original author .   When learning a new language, it's good to  pick the "best" features to do the work. After all, it has lots of "batteries" ;-))

Comment: Thanks I am a newby but if you guys have a better solution go right ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Would this helps you:  (lastly, you could modify the final concatenation as you like in terms of format...)

```py
    >>> line = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,300]
    >>> starts = [x for x in line if x-1 not in line]
    >>> ends = [y for y in line if y+1 not in line]
    >>> ranges = list((a,b) for a, b in zip(starts, ends))
    >>> ranges
    [(1, 7), (9, 12), (14, 19), (300, 300)]
    >>> results = [str(a)+'-'+str(b)  for a, b in ranges]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach seems to be working.  I was trying to make something that only iterated through the data once:

```
c = 0
result = ''
current = None
run = False

while c < len(line):

    if current == None:
        result += f'{line[c]}'
    elif line[c] - current == 1:
        run = True
        if c == len(line) - 1:
            result += f'-{line[c]}'
    elif run:
        result += f'-{current},{line[c]}'
        run = False
    else:
        result += f',{line[c]}'

    current = line[c]
    c += 1

print(result)
# 1-7,9-12,14-19,300
```

The first `if` checks if no numbers have been seen, i.e. only for the first number.  The second `if` notes that the current integer is one greater than the previous, also handling the when the end of the `line` is reached and is continuing a sequence.  The third notes that a sequence has been broken, and adds the output as such.  The last `else` block adds the current value following a non-sequence.